# How to permanently disable foreign key check

Tags: mysql

I have to cooperate with an old school programmer. A long time ago **he set up MySQL** database. When he created it, he used his primary language as a language for naming tables, columns etc.

Now I would like to have a relation graph for this database and I need it for Prisma to figure out relations between tables, thus **I would like to add foreign keys**, **but I cannot add them easily as he does violate them**.

I suppose the easiest thing to do would be to disable foreign key check `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, but this only ever lasts session. Is there a way around this?

---

Can I do something `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, but for every connected user, and ideal after DB restart too?

Comment: Have you tried `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` ? Otherwise you need to alter your table.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Indeed this worked, I think... If you want I'll accept this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Sets it only current session, even same user upon next reconnect won't have this setting.

`SET [SESSION] key = value` (`SESSION` is default and thus optional)

---

Sets it to all users, till next restart of MySQL server happens.

`SET GLOBAL key = value`

---

Same as global, but will also apply after restart. This will, in fact, change the config file of the MySQL server.

`SET PERSIST key = value` (`PERSIST` is only available since v8)

There is also `PERSIST_ONLY` which will apply the effect only after a restart.